# Dynamically Configuring a Zuul Proxy during Runtime?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I have a url path that looks like this:

```
/{identifier}/rest/of/resource/path
```

If the `identifier` is `A` then the request should go to `service_I`.  If the `identifier` is `B` then the request should also go to `service_I`.  If the `identifier` is `C`, then the request should go to `service_II`, and so on.

Later on a new `identifiers` `M` and `N` is added to the system and their requests should be routed to `service_IV`.

Is it possible to dynamically configure a Spring cloud zuul proxy to perform the tasks described above?

### Edit

This [question offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011047/how-do-i-wire-up-spring-oauth-using-spring-eureka) contains a different way to examine the question.

In it Zuul has the following configuration:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    <service_id>:
      path: /path/**
```

Zuul will collaborate with Eureka to find the `service-id` and return the host parameters so that the service can be accessed.  What if instead of `/path` we have `/{userID}` and the `userID` instances are distributed across several `service_id` hosts?

Can Zuul / the DiscoveryClient query Eureka for both the `service_id` and the `userID` to figure out which host is hosting the particular `userID`?

Comment: Are you using Spring Cloud Config server?  Have you tried changing the config for Zuul and then calling the `/refresh` endpoint?

Comment: I'll try experimenting with that.  Not sure whether Zuul supports many to one mappings - many identifiers to single server ...

Comment: Eureka does not currently have any facility for mapping serviceid and a query parameter to find a service host. You would need to write a custom zuul filter.

Comment: @spencergibb In my case I think the serviceid is probably redundant because the {identifier} parameter is globally unique, hence it should be sufficient for identification of the host(s) containing it.  Do you think the Zuul filter is still the right route?  I'm basically just replacing the serviceID with the {identifier}, which will most likely be a UUID string.

Comment: Yes, you would need to write a filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a custom `ZuulFilter` to accomplish this. Take a look at the [PreDecorationFilter](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/pre/PreDecorationFilter.java) for some hints as this is the filter responsible for handling `/path` where the path is a `service-id` (among other things).